# Reinforcement learning without trajectories

Tags: reinforcement-learning

Does it make sense to use Reinforcement Learning methods in an environment that does not have trajectories?

I have a lot of states and actions in my environment. However, there are no trajectories.

If the agent takes action $a$ in the state $s$, it reaches $s'$. In $s'$, it takes action $a'$ and reaches state $s''$. However, if it takes the reverse order of actions $a'$ and then $a$, it would reach the same state $s''$.

How reinforcement learning methods handle with this?

Comment: There is still a "trajectory" in your example, and in fact it also fits to a simple grid  world where $a$ is "go north", $a'$ is "go east" and $s''$ is the postion North East of  $s$. But that doesn't seem to match your concerns? I would guess that you mean that choice of $a$ has no impact on the transition $s \rightarrow s'$? Does $a$ influence anything else - what does the reward depend upon? Is the state progression deterministic in any useful way i.e. $s \rightarrow s'$ has a probability distribution that is not simply equiprobable random sampling from all possible states?

Comment: @NeilSlater Thanks for your answer.
I will make it more clear.
I have a set of actions that affect my environment, and I want to find them.
Executing these actions from any state affect the environment in the same way.
About the reward, I get a non-zero reward from the environment only at the end of the trajectory.
This reward is vary from state to state (most of the states are 0).

Comment: @NoamMoscovich Just edit your post to clarify the question and problem! This should also attract other people, because when you edit a post it will pop up again in the front page.

Comment: Please, I know this post is old, but try to clarify what your problem really is. As Neil said, it seems that there's a trajectory in your case.